# How do you remove ImageMagick without removing PlayOnLinux?

Tags: playonlinux, imagemagick

I am trying to delete ImageMagick, but each time I do, it also deletes PlayOnLinux. I just want to remove ImageMagick.

Comment: You "just" want to ride a bicycle having removed one wheel. The bicycle needs all of it's mechanical dependencies to function. Playonlinux needs all of it's software dependencies to function. That's not up to us -- the Playonlinux folks decided it.

Comment: `apt-cache showpkg playonlinux` shows you the dependencies - they're the packages that `playonlinux` uses to do what it does (maybe to copy images and make thumbnails?). You can force the removal `sudo dpkg --force-depends --remove imagemagick`; but likely playonlinux (and other programs) may stop working.

Comment: Do not remove imagemagick, it will break your system.

Answer (score 1):

The command `apt-cache depends playonlinux` shows that playonlinux depends on imagemagick, so imagemagick cannot be removed without also removing playonlinux. If you run `sudo apt-mark hold playonlinux` to put playonlinux on hold so that it can't be removed, then `sudo apt remove imagemagick` will do nothing except return an error message.